# Confrontation between two arrays

Tags: perl

I have a 2-D array as:

```
array[0][0]=1
array[0][1]=2
array[0][2]=4
array[1][0]=0
array[1][1]=2
```

I would like to check if at least one element between array[0][$i] and array[1][$j] is the same. I thought to a long way to do it, as

```
for my $i (0..($#{$array[0]}+1)){
    for my $j(0..($#{$array[1]}+1)){
      if (array[0][$i]==array[1][$j]){
          say "There is a match";
      }
    }
 }
```

It is possible to find a way to do it better? If I have a bigger array, there is a way to stop the loop when the two arays share at least an element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `intersect` from [Array::Utils](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Array-Utils/Utils.pm) to find the intersection of your two sub-arrays. If the resulting list is empty, there are no common elements.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Array::Utils qw(intersect);

my @array = (
    [ 1, 2, 4 ],
    [ 0, 2 ]
);  

say "There is a match" if intersect(@{$array[0]}, @{$array[1]});
```

If you want a count of the number of matches, simply call `intersect` in scalar context:

```
my $count = intersect(@{$array[0]}, @{$array[1]});
```

**NOTE ABOUT PERFORMANCE:** I ran a benchmark comparing my answer to [amon's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18360144/176646) using [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm) and `any` blows `intersect` out of the water by a couple orders of magnitude. This isn't a huge surprise since `any` and `intersect` do completely different things: `any` stops as soon as it finds a single match, while `intersect` finds *every* match. If you only care whether a match exists or not, I would definitely recommend the `any` approach since it will be significantly faster for any non-trivial data set. `intersect` would only be useful if you want a list of matches.

Comment: I want to associate a control scalar if there is a match; I wrote the last line as `my $count=0; $count =1 if intersect(@{$array[0]}, @{$array[1]}){ say $count; }` but I have the following error `syntax error at line 19, near "){"`; How can I associate the matching to a scalar?

Answer (score 3):

You can break out of a (labeled) loop. Note that your code is wrong because arrays are indexed zero-based. you want to loop from `0` to `$#array`, not from `1` to `$#array + 1` which happens to be `scalar @array` (unless you fiddle with certain variables).

```
my $found_same = 0;
my ($x, $y) = @array[0, 1];  # $x, $y are arrayrefs we want to loop over
my ($x_i, $y_i);

INDEX:
for $x_i (0 .. $#$x) {
  for $y_i (0 .. $#$y) {
    if ($x->[$x_i] == $y->[$y_i]) {
      $found_same = 1;
      last INDEX;
    }
  }
}

say "found same value $x->[$x_i] at indices $x_i, $y_i" if $found_same;
```

If you aren't interested in the indices, only in the presence of a same value, you should just loop over the values:

```
my $found_same = 0;
my ($x, $y) = @array[0, 1];
INDEX:
for my $x_val (@$x) {
  for my $y_val (@$y) {
    if ($x_val = $y_val) {
      $found_same = 1;
      last INDEX;
    }
  }
}

say "found some same value" if $found_same;
```

If we write that as a function, we can remove the ugly reassignment of variables, and can `return` to break the loops:

```
my $find_same = sub {
  my ($x, $y) = @_;
  for my $x_val (@$x) {
    for my $y_val (@$y) {
      return 1 if $x_val == $y_val;
    }
  }
  return 0;
};

say "found some same value" if $find_same->(@array[0, 1]);
```

With the help of `List::MoreUtils`, there is a very short way to write this:

```
use List::MoreUtils 'any';

my ($x, $y) = @array[0, 1];
say "found some same value" if any { my $val = $_; any { $val == $_ } @$y } @$x;
```

All of these solutions assume you only have numerical data.

Comment: I don't know why, when I try the third code, after I installed the `List::Util` and `List::MoreUtils`, I have always the error: `"any" is not exported by the List::Util module`.

Comment: @ValerioD.Ciotti corrected the typo: I meant `use List::MoreUtils 'any'`

Answer (score 0):

This code may have answered a different question. This checks whether the same value occurs twice anywhere in the array.

Hashes are good for checking whether a value has already been seen. Both code blocks here use the value in the array as the hash key. The first code below counts how many times an array value has been seen and reports when it goes above one. The second block holds the indices of where the value was seen so it can report both pairs of indices of where the value was found.

```
my %values;
INDEX:
for my $ii (0 .. $#array) {
    for my $jj ( 0..($#{$array[$ii]})){
        my $val = $array[$ii][$jj];
        if ( ++$values{$val} > 1 ) {
            say "found same value $val at indices $ii, $jj";
            last INDEX;
        }
    }
}

my %indices;
INDEX:
for my $ii (0 .. $#array) {
    for my $jj ( 0..($#{$array[$ii]})){
        my $val = $array[$ii][$jj];
        if ( defined $indices{$val} ) {
            say "found same value $val at indices $indices{$val} and at $ii, $jj";
            last INDEX;
        }
        $indices{$val} = "$ii, $jj";
    }
}
```